# How to make sure the font in powershell will same under winPE?

Tags: powershell

I have powershell script, I want to write some data to a file. If I run the script under powershell, the file will write properly. But when I execute under winPE, the file looks strange. like this

```
;**********  ATF Output  **********
਍㬀䈀甀椀氀搀开䤀䐀㴀㄀㠀圀圀儀㘀䈀吀㘀　㈀⌀匀䄀䈀䌀⌀䐀䄀䈀䌀ഀഀ
;Feature_Byte=3E3X476J6S6b7B7H7M7Q7T7W7maBapaqaubhcAdUdpdqgzhKhZjh.ma
਍㬀䴀䰀开倀爀攀昀椀砀㴀䐀倀䌀ഀഀ
;CRM=A1
਍㬀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀⨀ഀഀ
```

This the powershell script how I write the file.

```
$Outer = ";***********************************"
    $Header = ";**********  ATF Output  **********"
    $ML = $Global:SelectedFile_Name.Substring(0,11)
    $FB = ";Feature_Byte=3E3X476J6S6b7B7H7M7Q7T7W7maBapaqaubhcAdUdpdqgzhKhZjh.ma"

    # Prefix selection
    if ($NB.Checked -eq $true) {$Prefix = ";ML_Prefix=" + "BNB"}
    if ($DPC.Checked -eq $true) {$Prefix = ";ML_Prefix=" + "DPC"}

    # Creating SWPO
    Write-Host "Starting Creating SWPOs...."
    $count = 1
    Foreach ($key in $ini_file.($section).Keys)
    {
        try
        {
            $B_ID = ";Build_ID=" + $ML + "#" + "S" + $ini_file.($section)["$key"].Substring(0, 3) + "#" + "D" + $ini_file.($section)["$key"].Substring(0, 3)
            $CRM = ";CRM=$key"
            $Output_SWPO = $Header, $B_ID, $FB, $Prefix, $CRM, $Outer | Out-File $store\$ML`_$key -Force
```

The expectation file should be like this

```
;**********  ATF Output  **********
;Build_ID=18WWQ6BT602#SABC#DABC
;Feature_Byte=3E3X476J6S6b7B7H7M7Q7T7W7maBapaqaubhcAdUdpdqgzhKhZjh.ma
;ML_Prefix=DPC
;CRM=A1
;***********************************
```

Comment: You are looking for the `-Encoding` param I believe. Give that a go and try a few different options. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6

Comment: yes, Got it. Thanks buddy